# How to convert ImageSource to Bitmap for cross-platform project(xamarin)

Tags: android, xamarin, bitmap, converters, imagesource

I found an example, but this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689674/c-sharp-convert-wpf-image-source-to-a-system-drawing-bitmap)  use a "[Int32Rect](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.int32rect?view=netframework-4.7.2)", class of System.Windows, we can't use this library for android or ios

For bitmap, i use the [System.Drawing.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.5.0-preview1-25718-03)

```
public static System.Drawing.Bitmap BitmapSourceToBitmap2(BitmapSource srs)
        {
            int width = srs.PixelWidth;
            int height = srs.PixelHeight;
            int stride = width * ((srs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
            IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(height * stride);
                srs.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), ptr, height * stride, stride);
                using (var btm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, stride, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed, ptr))
                {
                    // Clone the bitmap so that we can dispose it and
                    // release the unmanaged memory at ptr
                    return new System.Drawing.Bitmap(btm);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
            }
        }
```

So, how to convert ImageSource to Bitmap for cross-platform project?

I tried to follow [guide](https://medium.com/@hakimgulamali88/a-helper-for-converting-a-xamarin-forms-imagesource-to-the-respective-native-images-56a5aaf98156), there was incomplete information in it and I tried to fill in the understatement on my own

The project even compiles! However, when I try to get the result from the GetBitmapFromImageSourceAsync (…) method, the application freezes (infinite loop)

```
var test = GetBitmapFromImageSourceAsync(image, Android.App.Application.Context);
var bitmap = test.Result;
```

Please see why it does not work? Or please give me a link to your project and I’ll figure it out

https://github.com/StriBog45/XamarinImage

Comment: I'd try using SkiaSharp to do this

Comment: Here is a similar issue https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43023/xamarin-forms-image-to-convert-bitmap

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I tried to download the zip file from the response, but could not compile it for verification. I see that he uses XLabs, I will try to understand the code

Comment: I am the author of that blog and I think your issue is that you are using Application Context what you should rather do is use the [CurrentActivity plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin)

Comment: Also, I see you using `System.Drawing.Bitmap` whereas Android uses `Android.Graphics.Bitmap`

Comment: @G.hakim I did everything, but it didn't help, github updated

Comment: @G.hakim I DID IT! My problem was in synchronizing the function, or rather in its absence

Comment: @StriBog i am not sure what you mean here but anyway well done secondly i just wanted you to point out the issues you faced with regards to understanding in my blog!