# I have this "Error Can not resolve reference: 'Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging', referenced by `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Android.Bindings`

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this "Error  Can not resolve reference: `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging`, referenced by `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Android.Bindings`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging`, or remove the reference to `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Android.Bindings`.

Comment: This could be it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893523/error-package-com-google-firebase-messaging-does-not-exist/48922248#48922248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read twice it says if you want to use `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Android.Bindings` you have to install `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging`.

Your solution is to install `Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging` NuGet package.

Or

If you don't want to use `Microsoft.AppCenter.Push.Android.Bindings` then remove this NuGet package from your package

Comment: Hi, I also solved by installing the missing NuGet, but my question is for most NuGet I used, no reference error pops, what is the difference that makes the referenced NuGet (like Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging here) need to be installed again? Thanks.